# Switch between marked occurrences shortcut in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, switch-statement

I wonder if there is some shortcut for switching between marked occurrences in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 buttons in the toolbar - 'Previous Annotation' (the icon has an up arrow) and 'Next Annotation' (the icon has a down arrow) - which allow you to move from one annotation to another. Annotations are the markers in the editor - errors, warnings, breakpoints, **occurrences** etc. You can configure which annotations should the buttons traverse through by clicking on the dropdown (inverted triangle) icon next to the toolbar buttons.

Keyboard shortcut for 'Next Annotation' is 'Ctrl+.', this is also shown if you hover over the toolbar button.

PS: You might also find it useful to glance through the [JDT tips and tricks](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) document. The above mentioned toolbar buttons are also described in the document.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks to this post I finally realized why "Ctrl+." only worked for hopping to the next error while it did nothing for search results -- the annotation selection on the dropdown for "search results" was not checked.  I've enabled that and now navigating to the next search occurrence is working in the editor window and not just on the 'Search" tab.  Thanks a bunch!